# Sound on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have one problem, i have experienced blue screen on windows 7 and after restart all system sounds are not working, sounds from plugins are not workings (flash player in any browser) but sounds that I playback trough winamp, windows media player, bs player are working fine. When I go to sound settings for system sounds and I chose sound for example windows startup and I click test it doesn't play.

I don't know what to do?

Comment: I have also reinstalled my sound card

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No solution for this, only one was to reinstall my system.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a hardware or a software issue.

Try that to solve a software issue:
- see your device manager (win+break then "device manager"). If some drivers are marked with exclamation or question mark, see what is the problem with them (properties). Try to reinstall them and test the sound
- reinstall your codecs (try K-Lite Mega Codec Pack in www.superdownloads.com.br) and test the sound
- reinstall your sound drivers. Although is is not marked with exclamation or question mark, remove current driver and reinstall it. Test the sound

Comment: no, everything is ok, i can watch movies, play music, everything but when it comes to system sounds there is problem. I can locate sound that is selected for particular notice and i can play it, but when system needs to play it it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Then try to get Windows updates. If it does not fix it, then reinstall Windows 7; try to use another Windows 7 DVD.